# How do I specify parameters in a KQL query?

Tags: parameters, kql

I am trying to execute a KQL query against an Azure Data Explorer cluster using query parameters and the .NET Kusto SDK.

I have tried placing the parameters inside braces {} and without braces.

I have read the documentation about passing parameters to the query, but I can't find any examples of how the query should look when passed to Azure Data Explorer via the .NET SDK.

My query works in the Kusto.Explorer tool when I set the parameters in the tool but I'm having no luck when using the SDK.

```
var queryParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "myscope", "scope001" },
                { "startdate", "2019-01-01" },
                { "enddate", "2019-01-30" },
                { "author", "Bob Jammo" }
            };

var query = @"declare query_parameters (myscope:string, startdate:string, enddate:string, author:string);
                            Events 
                            | where Scope == ""{myscope}"" 
                                and EventTime between (datetime({startdate}) .. datetime({enddate}))
                                and EventType == ""product""
                                and User.Email <> """"
                            | mv-expand Payload.products
                            | where Payload_products.authors contains ""{author}""
                            | distinct DeviceId
                            | count";

using (var client = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdxConnectionString"]))
{
    var clientRequestProperties = new Kusto.Data.Common.ClientRequestProperties(
        options: null,
        parameters: queryParameters);

    clientRequestProperties.ClientRequestId = StepsBase.ScenarioScope;

    using (var reader = client.ExecuteQuery(query, clientRequestProperties))
    {
        reader.Read();
        return Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
    }
}
```

I get an error that indicates to me that the parameter value has not been set: "Syntax error: Query could not be parsed: Failed to parse datetime literal: 'datetime(startdate)'"

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the error message, it's cause you're using `datetime({startdate})` instead of `todatetime({startdate})`.

Regardless, you could also consider changing the type of `startdate` and `enddate` to be `datetime` instead of `string` to begin with (and adjust their definition in the .NET dictionary)